# React: Como crear un Array de objetos con un formulario?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Es una pregunta sin código. Quiero crear un Arreglo donde cada vez que escriba un nombre y apellido en un formulario, se añada un objeto del nombre y apellido a este arreglo. Como podría hacerlo?

Comment: que has intentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo una solución a ver si es lo que buscas

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid"

export default function App() {
  const [nombre, setNombre] = useState('');
  const [apellido, setApellido] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const nombreOnchangeHandler = evento =>{
        setNombre(evento.target.value)
  }
  const apellidoOnchangeHandler = evento =>{
        setApellido(evento.target.value)
  }
  
  const buttonOnsubmitHandler = evento =>{
    evento.preventDefault();
    console.log('enviando...')
    const datosNuevos = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      nombre: nombre,
      apellido: apellido
    }
    setApellido('')
    setNombre('')
    const newData = [...data, datosNuevos]
    setData(newData)
    console.log(newData)
    
  }


    return (
        <form 
        onSubmit={buttonOnsubmitHandler}
        >
            <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Nombre"
                name="text"
                value={nombre}
                onChange={nombreOnchangeHandler}
            />
      <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Apellidos"
                name="text"
                value={apellido}
                onChange={apellidoOnchangeHandler}
            />
            <button 
      >
                Añadir
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Lo puedes probar aquí https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-pond-vl78tb , el resultado lo puedes ver por consola.

La verdad, falta contexto así que lo que te he pasado es una idea básica, tomas de tu formulario el valor de los inputs y los almacenas es sus respectivas variables haciendo uso del hook `useState`, también creas una variable llamada `data` para este caso que será donde almacenes el array con tus datos, cada vez que el formulario realice el evento submit, lo que hará será tomar los valores de los inputs, y asignárselos al nuevo objeto que creamos `datosNuevos`, y finalmente haremos una nueva variable `newData` donde cargarás todos los datos almacenados que ya tenías, y como última instancia, los nuevos datos, tras esto haciendo uso de la nueva variable creada `newData`, actualizaremos el array con `setData(newData)`

El `id` yo se lo he puesto porque te hará falta seguramente para poder tomar referencias de cada "usuario", si no lo necesitas puedes omitirlo.

Un saludo.

Comment: Era lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias por la increíble explicación!